# Javascript additions

Tags: javascript

I have a JS code whitch I wrote to add the values of variables together, but it just writes the values next to each other, it does not add them together. How to I add these values together?

JS:

```
function display(){
    let dollarvalue = `$ ${motorverseny}+${motorprofi}+${motoralap}+${turboverseny}+${turboprofi}+${turboalap}+${ecuverseny}+${ecuprofi}+${ecualap}+${valtoverseny}+${valtoprofi}+${valtoalap}+${felfuggesztesverseny}+${felfuggesztesprofi}+${felfuggesztesalap}`;
    let ppvalue = `${motorvenom}+${turbovenom}+${ecuvenom}+${valtovenom}+${felfuggesztesvenom}`;
    document.getElementById("pptext").innerHTML = `${ppvalue}`;
    document.getElementById("dollartext").innerHTML = `${dollarvalue}`;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h3 class="dollar">Dollar:</h3>
<h5 id="dollartext" style="color: #7cc576;"></h5>
<h3 class="pp">PP:</h3>
<h5 id="pptext" style="color: blue;"></h5>
```

Comment: No, you're not adding anything together here. You're literally creating a string which contains numbers and `+` signs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you're not actually summing the values, but you are using [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) incorrectly. You need to place the variables within the curly braces and sum them. Here is an example:

```
let var1 = 10;
let var2 = 20;
let dollarValueWrong = `$ ${var1}+${var2}`; // results in the string `$ 10+20`
let dollarValueCorrect = `$ ${var1+var2}`; // results in the string `$ 30`
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing this for me.

Answer (score 0):

How about removing the interpolation?

```
let ppvalue = motorvenom+turbovenom+…
```